# To embed PDF animation in latex document

Tags: animations, animate, includegraphics

I have created an animation by latex with `\usepackage{animate}`. I added this PDF-animation to another latex file by `\includegraphics{}` or `\includepdf{}`, but it is invisible in new file.

This is a simplified sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\setlatintexfont[scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,poster=first,loop]{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\newframe
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) rectangle (3,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

%...

\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

My problem is only "to embed PDF animation in another latex document".
You asked a minimal code, so I made a simple code for you. It is not XY-Problem.
The result of above code is a PDF file. I want to add this file in my next file. the second file has \usepackage{xepersian}.
I added those three inactive lines to show you the error of using animation codes in my final file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settexfont[scale=1.0]{Yas}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{BC.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Actually this is my second code. When I run second code with final file of first code (BC.pdf) I have a white blank paper. But I have a result, if I replace another PDF file.

Comment: Please post a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: As is, you are trying to solve an [↗XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your code does not compile for some reason (original problem X). You are trying to work around the problem using another method which fails too (problem Y) and you  ask for help solving Y. Could you please reformulate your question to clearly state the original problem X, adding the error message you get (mentioned in your first comment below the answer)?

Comment: Your actual problem X is: How to use `animate` in a document using the `xepersian` package. Your attempt to work around this problem is to embed a PDF with animation produced *without* `xepersian` into a secondary document using `xepersian`. It is giving rise to problem Y, because such kind of PDF doesn't seem to leave the animation intact.

Comment: The command `\setlatintexfont` doesn't seem to be defined. At least not by the packages loaded.

Comment: The command `\settexfont` of the second code isn't defined either.

Answer (score 5):

This is an [↗XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem):

- Secondary, **Y Problem**: Embedding a PDF with an  `animate`-generated animation into another document as an attempt to work around the **actual problem X** below.

  Answer:

  Any interactivity in the included PDF, such as `animate`-generated animations, gets lost. The same happens to `hyperref`-generated links and bookmarks, to PDF layers, embedded files, multimedia etc.

  To transfer an animation, just copy the original code for building the animation into the LaTeX source of the destination document.
- Actual, **X Problem**: A document using packages `animate` and `xepersian` at the same time does not compile, but produces an error:

  ```
  Package ifthen Error: Boolean @anim@morejs undefined.
  ```

---

Solution to original **Problem X**:

You should use an up-to-date TeX installation and packages. With TeXLive 2017 (frozen<sup>1</sup>), there is **no** problem using `animate` and `xepersian` in the same document:

[image]

(I put [↗**`Yas.ttf`**](https://fontlibrary.org/assets/downloads/yas/6d496aade0637f6ff0aed373a19aa54a/yas.zip) into the current directory for compilation with `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas.ttf}

\begin{document}\Huge\centering
این طرحنما میآزماید نگاره و اندازه و شکل را

\begin{animateinline}[controls,poster=first,loop]{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,fill=red] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newframe
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,fill=green] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newframe
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,fill=blue] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As of 5th March 2018, TeXLive-2017 does not get package updates anymore; versions of installed packages may lag behind the versions on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg). TeXLive-2018 is to be released to the public on [30th April 2018](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), allowing the user to update packages via its package manager `tlmgr` again, either via command line (`tlmgr update --self --all`) or via the graphical user interface. Package updates are started manually and should be carried out regularly to take advantage of bug fixes and new features of installed packages, as well as of new packages that appear on CTAN.

Comment: I cannot copy the code. It is impossible because when I use \usepackage{xepersian} and \usepackage{animate} both together, TexStudio shows this error:   package ifthen error: Boolean

Comment: Please add a minimal example, as suggested by @Henri . In doubt, follow the link in his comment on how to set up an MWE.

Comment: \documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\setlatintexfont[scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,poster=first,loop]{1}

\newframe

\begin{tikzpicture}

\drow (0,0) rectangle (4,5);

\end{tikzpicture}

...

\end{animateinline}

\end{document}

Comment: This is my sample code. If you hide xepersian and set text font, it is correct and will be run.
But when you use xepersian to write Farsi, you will see those errors.

Comment: Why didn't you insert the code into the question?

Comment: Where have to I insert the code?

Comment: At the moment I'm thinking about \includestandalone{} code. As I understood it is useful for animation insert.

Comment: Not a good idea. You will run into an [↗XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).